# ImageBackground not cover background on resizeMode repeat

Tags: react-native

I am using ImageBackground with `resizeMode={'repeat'}`. But it doesnt cover all background. When i change resizeMode to `contain` it does fit background

```
render(
       return (
               <ImageBackground source={require('./img/download.jpg')} style= 
                         {styles.container} resizeMode={'repeat'}>

               </ImageBackground>
       )

)


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      flex: 1,
      padding: 0
   }
});
```

[Link to image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ6j5.png)

Comment: Tested the same piece of code with some other image with different image and it works fine , [Click here to check](https://snack.expo.io/r1a2MlU-r).
So i think there would be an issue with the image used as background, can you share the image?

Comment: Are you check react-native-version?  this problem solved since 6/27/18
·

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
render(
       return (
            <View style={{ flex:1, position:'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, }}>
               <ImageBackground source={require('./img/download.jpg')} style= 
                         {styles.container} resizeMode={'repeat'}>

               </ImageBackground>
            </View>
       )

)
```

```css
container: {
 flex:1, width: null, height: null
}
```